# Как вырезать из вывода колонки из SQL запроса два последних символа?

Tags: sql, oracle

Запрос:

```
select LTRIM(RUN_DURATION ) 
from SYS.USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS 
WHERE LOG_ID = 218737;
```

возвращает:`+000 00:01:27`.
Мне нужны только секунды т.е. от 0 до 59 - два последних символа.

Сам догадался только до `TRIM`:

```
select LTRIM(RUN_DURATION , '+000 00:00'))
from SYS.USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS 
WHERE LOG_ID = 218737;
```

Но значение минут может быть разное и данный вариант не подходит.

Как отформатировать вывод до двух знаков справа?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select SUBSTR(RUN_DURATION,12)
   from SYS.USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
   ...
```

Берем символы начиная с 12. Если надо вырезать из середины, то третьим параметром substr можно задавать длину.

Comment: Mike спасибо! То что нужно!

Answer (score 3):

Если задача стоит:

> от 0 до 59 - два последних символа

, то вырезать удобней с конца, указав негативное значение для начальной позиции:

```
select substr ('+000 00:01:27', -2) sec from dual; 

SEC 
----
27
```

---

Следует учесть, что колонка `USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS.RUN_DURATION` объявлена как `INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(0)`. И хотя точность для долей секунды указана 0, но неявное преобразование в строку зависит от настроек сессии и может привести к весьма неожиданому результату:

```
select cast (to_dsinterval ('+000 00:01:27') as interval day (3) to second (0)) ds 
from dual; 

DS                 
-------------------
+00 00:01:27.000000
           --^^^^^^
```

Поэтому для, цитирую: *нужны только секунды*, правильней будет так:

```
select to_char (extract (second from to_dsinterval ('+000 00:01:07')), 'fm09') ds 
from dual; 

SEC 
----
07
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, правильнее было бы не обрезать, а воспользоваться extract'ором:
    select extract(second from run_duration)
      from SYS.DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS;

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.